# How to create a .wav file from SpeechID such as 3D5FFCDA-4D8B-4F2E-AE95-D86B560F4F85

Tags: python, wav

I have a different SpeechID where I want to create a .wav file from this ID's. Any idea how?

Answer (score 1):

You can't:

https://www.telekom.com/en/company/details/speechid-the-simple-way-of-identification-538268

> [SpeechID is] A sequence of numbers is created from all the characteristics, a so-called hash. A hash can be imagined as a one-way street: a speech file cannot be created from the hash [...]